# TYPO3 Core exception: "Id was out of domain" instead of Error 404

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

because of some alterings in the page structure many of our pages changed the pid. It does not matter in SEO terms because of speaking urls but there are a bunch of third party links with wrong pids, e. g.:

```
https://www.myDomain.de/index.php?id=46&no_cache=1&sword_list[0]=someWord
```

The page with uid 46 exists but is not the meant one, and it now resides under a different domain. So the result is the following exception:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1518472189: 
ID was outside the domain | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\PageNotFoundException 
thrown in file typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/ErrorController.php 
in line 80. Requested URL: 
https://www.myDomain.de/index.php?id=46&no_cache=1&sword_list[0]=someWord
```

My question:

Can i tell TYPO3 not to throw an exception but to treat all Outside Domain Events simply as 404 with a redirect to the error page?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible by ading an 404 error handling in Site Management module:
Site Management -> Sites -> Yoursite -> Tab "Error hanling" -> Create new

Comment: I think the problem is that this does not work when out-of-domain (which happens when the page UID could not be found in the DB any more)

Comment: Hm, does work here on a TYPO3 9.5 multidomainsite:
https://www.mydomain.de/?id=6 where page with uid 6 ist from another domain in that installation.
Site config is like:
How to handle Errors: PHP Class,
ErrorHandler Class Target (FQCN): Vendor\ExtPage\Error\ErrorHandler,
Class implementation: class ErrorHandler extends TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\PageErrorHandler\FluidPageErrorHandler...

Comment: What does "does not work mean"? Do you get any error message in the frontend or in the logs?

Comment: I get my  custom 404 page as configured in my ErrorHandler class using the fluid StandaloneView and returning new HtmlResponse($content, $this->statusCode);

Comment: that sounds like it works. I might have misread your comment as not working ;)

Comment: We do have a 404 definition on every site but with "Show content from site". This does throw "Oops, an error occurred!" in frontend and a log entry in the backend if id=123 is from an other site. You mean it would work with a custom php class to handle the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Showing your 404-page with the correct status code in that case is in my experience unfortunately not too obvious.

The simplest for `?id=...` with deleted/moved pages (which because of that do not map to the correct site) is to do redirects to useful pages with EXT:redirect or on the webserver level.

That's an example with EXT:redirect:

[image: EXT:redirect]

If there's nothing comparable in the new content that you could redirect to, you can show your 404-page, e.g. by a passthrough (`[PT]` with Apache mod_rewrite https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You should make sure to send a 404 status in that case. (E.g. through .htaccess, a userFunc on the 404-page, ...).

I hope somebody else has a simpler idea.

Comment: Good idea for few pages - in my case we have to deal with a few thousend pages ... :-)